# Accessing document string values in an ElasticSearch native script

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm creating an ElasticSearch native script, and I'm struggling to get a `List<String>` value of some field in my doc.

Here is what I tried:

`List<String> tmp = ((ScriptDocValues.Strings) doc().get("my_field")).getValues();`

And here is the exception thrown:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings.getValues()Lorg/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/util/StringArrayRef;`

I can't figure out why it doesn't work, given the [code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.java) of this module...

Comment: if your class is compiling, and you have such an error at runtime, then you probably have another (older...) version of this class in your classpath at runtime ... Just a idea, i'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compiled your code with an older version of elasticsearch (0.20.x or older) than the one you're using at runtime (0.90.x).

The error you get says that the not found method has a `StringArrayRef` return type. It seems weird since you assign the result to a `List<String>`, but that works at compile time since the `StringArrayRef` class extended `AbstractList<String>` before it was removed from the elasticsearch codebase. I guess the method was removed during the fielddata refactoring that has been done a few months ago. The method that you see on master and 0.90.x returns now a `List<String>`. Just update your elasticsearch dependency (use the same that you're using at runtime), recompile and you should be good to go!

Comment: Perfectly right. I forgot to change my Maven dependencies for compilation... Thanks a lot!